# Create new column in each dataframe of list and fill with string from character vector based on position (R)

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of data frames and a character vector with strings.  The number of dataframes and the number of strings in the `chr` are the same.

I'd like to populate a specific column in each dataframe in the list with the string at the corresponding position in the character vector

```
dfs<-list(mtcars[,1:4], iris[,1:4])
dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(x) transform(x, mycol=""))

z <- c("red", "blue")
```

As the final output I'd like

`dfs[[1]]$mycol` to be populated with `red`  and

`dfs[[2]]$mycol` to be populated with `blue`

Conceptually, I think I need to do something like this:

`dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(n) dfs[[n]]$mycol <- z[n])`, but I get the error

> Error in z[n] : invalid subscript type 'list'

The real data is a list of 97 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try creating directly `mycol` with `mapply()`:

```
#Data
dfs<-list(mtcars[,1:4], iris[,1:4])
z <- c("red", "blue")
#Code
L <- mapply(function(x,y) {x$mycol<-y;return(x)},x=dfs,y=z,SIMPLIFY = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're after

```
lapply(1:n, function(x) transform(dfs[x], mycol = z[x]))
```

When you want to perform an `apply` by passing an index on several objects, simply `apply` on `1:n` then pass this as an argument to the different objects within the anonymous function.

---

EDIT `transform` only works with all objects contained in the same environment. So it throws the error `object not found` with the previous code because `dfs` exists the `.GlobalEnv` while `x` exists only in the function environments.

The below code works

```
lapply(c(1:n), function(x) {
  toreplace <<- z[x] # forcing to parent envir using <<-
  base::transform(dfs[x], mycol = toreplace)
})
```

Comment: Hm, produces this error: Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'x' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:n :
 Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'x' not found

Answer (score 0):

We could use `Map` with `transform` in `base R`

```
Map(transform, dfs, mycol = z)
```

---

Or `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(dfs, z, ~ .x %>%
                   mutate(mycol = .y))
```